# I do not know how to properly use CMTimeRange and CMTime in Swift or Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, waveform

Good morning.
 
First of all, I have been studying Swift and I have not started to develop IOS in less than 3 weeks.
 
And I want to implement the function that the current user's music file (mp3) is taken and the waveform is displayed and played back.
 
We are using an open source called SCWaveformView to show the waveform.

Here's [SCWaveformView](https://github.com/rFlex/SCWaveformView)! 
The usage of the library mentioned above is as follows.

```
    // Setting the asset
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"blabla.mp3"]];
    waveformView.asset = asset;

    // Show only the first second of your asset
    waveformView.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1));

    // Use it inside a scrollView
    SCScrollableWaveformView *scrollableWaveformView = [SCScrollableWaveformView new];
    scrollableWaveformView.waveformView; // Access the waveformView from there
```

For example, I have an MP3 file of 3 minutes 25 seconds.
 
You can display a 15-second waveform for this file to the user and scroll to see additional waveforms.
 
In other words, the maximum length of a user-visible waveform is 15 seconds.
 
You can scroll through the waveforms and view MP3 files in 15 second increments.
 
Through scrolling
If the start time is 2 minutes and 15 seconds, you can see the waveform up to 2 minutes and 30 seconds.
 
If the start time is 2 minutes and 20 seconds, you can see the waveform up to 2 minutes 45 seconds.

The library seems not to be a problem, but I am having trouble understanding CMTimeRange and CMTime.
 
Scrolling is slow and sometimes does not work. The following error message appears:

```
2016-12-12 15:29:03.568654 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.200 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.200 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.584947 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.240 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.240 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.585166 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.240 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.240 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.602243 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.280 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.280 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.618334 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.460 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.460 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.634987 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.480 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.480 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.651538 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.480 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.480 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.668358 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.720 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.720 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.697401 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.340 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.340 introduced due to very low timescale
2016-12-12 15:29:03.715348 AppName[7765:2094292] CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.480 seconds, timescale 1): warning: error of -0.480 introduced due to very low timescale
```

My problematic code is below.

```
    let musicAsset = AVAsset(url: (item?.assetURL)!)

    self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.asset = musicAsset

    self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.precision = 0.25

    self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.timeRange.start, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(15, 1));
```

I think I am misunderstanding CMTimeRange and CMTime, but I do not know the exact problem when I read the official document.
How do I resolve the issue and derive the results described above?
Thanks in advance.

[image: This is the current state.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above problem with the code below.

```
let musicAsset = AVAsset(url: (item?.assetURL)!)

    self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.asset = musicAsset
    self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.precision = 1

    var duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds( 1.0 * CMTimeGetSeconds(self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.asset.duration), 100000)

    self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 10000), duration);
    let start = self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.timeRange.start
    duration = CMTime(seconds: 15, preferredTimescale: 1)

    self.scwaveScrollView.waveformView.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration)
```